# CSS overlay image text with hover function

Tags: css, image, hover, overlay

I want to show my text just on the top of my image like in the picture below:

That's the css style I used by its shown on the middle of the page .

```
#imge .text {
                            position:relative;
                            opacity:1;
                            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                            color: white;
                            bottom:80px;
                            left:0px;
                            visibility:hidden;

                            }

                            #imge:hover .text {

                            font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
                            color: #ffffff;
                            font-size: 2em;
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 50%;
                            left: 50%;  
                            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                            visibility: visible; 

                            }
```

[image]

Comment: Please include you current approach - supply sufficient code to demonstrate to us what you've done so far, and how you've attempted to do this yourself.

Comment: @Serlite look above i updated my question

Comment: That's a start - but we need to know how your markup is structured since that affects the structure of the necessary CSS. Having enough CSS/HTML to reproduce what you're showing in your screenshot would be ideal.

Comment: Indeed. The answer is to add `position:relative` to the styles for `#imge`, but we don't know that, do we.